# A map without fixed points - two wrong approaches

Tags: differential-topology

For the unit sphere $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$
let $f : S^n \to S^n$ be the map reversing the signs of all
but one coordinate,
$$f(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n) = (x_0, -x_1, \dots, -x_n):$$

> (a) Compute the Lefschetz number $L(f)$.

My attempt to this question is [Lefschetz number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450808/lefschetz-number/452097#452097).

> (b) For which values of $n$ is $f$ homotopic to a map without fixed points?

First consider

> **Poincare-Hopf Index Theorem.** If $\vec{v}$ is a smooth vector field on the compact, oriented manifold $X$ with only finitely many zeros, then the global sum of the indices of $\vec{v}$ equals the Euler characteristic of $X$.

The [Euler characteristic of an $n$-sphere is $1 + (-1)^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453176/euler-characteristic-of-sphere-is-1-1n?lq=1) Hence, the degree of $f$ is $2$ if $k$ is even, and $0$ otherwise by Poincare-Hopf Index Theorem.

> **The Hopf Degree Theorem.** Two maps of a compact, connected, oriented $k$-manifold $X$ into $S^k$ are homotopic if and only if they have the same degree.

We attempt a homotopy with $f$ and the antipodal map. They both are compact, connected, oriented $k$-manifold $X$ into $S^k$. So they are homotopic if and only if they have the same degree.

Based on Jared's absolutely worth reading answer [The degree of antipodal map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452962/the-degree-of-antipodal-map/452966#452966) is $(-1)^{k+1}$.

**So, I am completely wrong here!**

**Alternatively,**

Consider the homotopy $f_t = f + t(-2x_1)$, so that $f_0 = f$, but $f_1$ is the antipodal map.

**So it is irrelevant to $n$! This also can't be right..**

Comment: A fixed point of a function/map $f\colon S\to S$ is an element $x\in S$ such that $f(x)=x$. That should answer your question about what a map without fixed points would be.

Comment: Oh yes, I know the definition, but I am trying to figure out which map I should think of. I actually think $f$ itself is...

Comment: $f(1,0,\dots,0)=(1,0,\dots,0)$

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer, I've thought about this, but it is not a map without fixed points... It is a map completely are fixed points..

Comment: Huh? Your $f$ has exactly one fixed point.

Comment: $f$ is just identity map - or your are implying restrict the domain to be $(1,0,\dots, 0)$? Thank you @dfeuer.

Comment: I mean exactly two fixed points.

Comment: Well if it is homotopic to any map without fixed points, it's likely homotopic to the antipodal map, so for certain $n$ try to construct a homotopy between $f$ and the antipodal map.

Comment: Yes Indeed @PVAL, but I think $f$ is just an antipodal map with first coordinate fixed...?

Comment: @WishingFish, the point I was trying to make was that though obviously this map has fixed points, the antipodal map does not. So if you can show it is homotopic to the antipodal map then it is homotopic to a "map with no fixed points". I have seen this problem stated as when is $f$ is homotopic to the antipodal map. I am really not sure why that is enough (Maybe by removing a point and applying Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem), but I do think that it is.

Comment: Oh, so you mean do **not** invoke the degree theorem, but instead show $f$ is homotopic to antipodal map @PVAL?

Comment: Oh no, I tried as updated... my attempt is incorrect, please help @PVAL..

Comment: Are you really sure that your $f_t$ is really a homotopy between maps on the sphere? I mean, if you think about sphere $S^k$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x^2_i = 1$, $f_0$ and $f_1$ are obviously maps of sphere, but all the intermediate maps doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 3):

To compute the Lefschetz number, you just look at the induced map on homology. $H_0(S^n)=H_n(S^n)=\mathbb Z$ and all other homology groups are zero. The induced map $H_0(f)\colon \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ is the identity, as is always the case for a map from a connected space to itself. Since $f$ is invertible, $H_n(f)=\pm\mathrm{id}$. To figure out which one, we need to figure out whether it preserves or reverses orientation. If you write down charts and an orientation in these charts, you can see that $f$ preserves orientation iff $n$ is even. (In fact, $f$ is the suspension of the antipodal map on $S^{n-1}$.) So $H_n(f)=(-1)^n\mathrm{id}$. Thus the Lefschetz number is
$$L(f)=(-1)^0Tr(H_0(f))+(-1)^nTr(H_n(f))=1+(-1)^n(-1)^n=2.$$

Comment: When I use the Guillemin and Pollack definition of Lefschetz number I get the same answer as @amine. But I follow this answer and it makes sense to me too. What gives? Do these definitions only agree up to sign?

Comment: @Max: looks like the definitions agree up to a factor of $(-1)^n$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

WishingFish, beware $f_t$ is not an homotopy $f_t(x)\not\in S^n$ (for $t\neq0,1$).

The two fixed points of $f$ are : $A=(1,0,...,0)$ and $B=(-1,0,...,0)$.

Let $e_i,\ (i=1,...,n+1)$ denotes the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Since $T_AS^n=<e_2,...,e_{n+1}>$, if $\gamma$ is a smooth curve in $S^n$ passing through $A$, such that $\gamma'(0)=e_i$ then:
$$T_Af(e_i)=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t))=-e_i$$
so that $D_Af=-\mathrm{Id}$ and also $D_Bf=-\mathrm{Id}$. The Lefschetz number is:
$$L(f)=\mathrm{sign}\det(T_Af-\mathrm{Id})+\mathrm{sign}\det(T_Bf-\mathrm{Id})=(-1)^n+(-1)^n=2(-1)^n.$$