# What is the meaning of the symbol $\pitchfork$?

Tags: notation

I have seen this symbol in the formulation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453056/preimage-orientation). There, it is said:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a smooth map with $f \pitchfork Z$.

I was googling, but I haven't found any answers.

Comment: It is a terrifying symbol. It looks like the wand of Satan. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means transversality. Spesifically, that the image of $f$ is transverse to $Z$.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_%28mathematics%29

Two submanifolds $U$ and $V$ of a manifold $M$ are called transversal at $x\in Z$ if $$T_xU+T_xV=T_xM$$
and simply transversal if they are transversal at all intersection points. Note that the sum is not direct. We identify $T_xU$ and $T_xV$ by the appropriate subspaces of $T_xM$.

Comment: 'Transversal' is a noun; 'transverse' is the corresponding adjective.