# The degree of antipodal map, composition of reflections?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here is a bit from Hatcher's book:

[image]

I don't understand part (f); why is the antipodal map the composition of $n+1$ reflections? Even if I accept that, I still don't know why does it have degree $(-1)^{n+1}$. What would that mean for $S^2$? We fix the equator $S^1$ and take every other point $x$ to $-x$? And then we are doing this for $S^1$? That sounds a little pointless. In general if $\operatorname{deg}f=x$ and $\operatorname{deg}g=y$ then what is $\operatorname{deg}f\circ g$? It's $xy$ I guess.

Comment: On $S^2$. You take the map $f_x \colon S^2 \to S^2 \,\, f_x(x,y,z) = (-x,y,z)$ and define $f_y$ and $f_z$ in a similar way. Then observe that the antipodal map $-\mathbb{1}$ is just $-\mathbb{1} = f_x \circ f_y \circ f_z$. By (e), each of the $f_i$ has degree $-1$, so by (d) you have $\mathrm{deg}\, (-\mathbb{1}) = (-1)(-1)(-1) = -1$. Just do the same things on $S^n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The degree of antipodal map.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452962/the-degree-of-antipodal-map)

Comment: which page of Hatcher?

Answer (score 7):

Consider $S^n$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then a point $x$ in $S^n$ is given by an $(n+1)$--tuple $(x_0,\dotsc,x_n)$, hence the antipodal map is given by 
$$
(x_0,\dotsc,x_n)\mapsto (-x_0,\dotsc,-x_n)
$$
we can get this map by composing all $n+1$ reflections with respect to the hyperplanesplanes orthogonal to the coordinate axes. (I.e. the maps
$$
(x_0,\dotsc, x_k,\dotsc,x_n)\mapsto (x_0,\dotsc,-x_k,\dotsc,x_n)
$$
Furthermore, since homology is functorial, we have $H_n(f\circ g,\mathbb{Z}) = H_n(f,\mathbb{Z})\circ H_n(g,\mathbb{Z})$. Thus given $f,g\colon S^n\to S^n$ with 
$$
H_n(f,\mathbb{Z})=f_*\colon H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})
$$
$$x\mapsto\alpha x$$
and
$$
H_n(g,\mathbb{Z})=g_*\colon H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})
$$

$$x\mapsto\beta x
$$
we have $(f\circ g)_*(x) = f_*\circ g_*(x) = f_*(\beta x) = \alpha\beta x$, so as you assumed $\operatorname{deg}(f\circ g) = \operatorname{deg}(f)\operatorname{deg}(g)$. And combining both results, we get the degree $(-1)^{n+1}$ for the antipodal map on $S^n$.

Comment: If it is $S^\infty$ how to compute the deg ? For example, $E$ is infinity dimensional Banach space,$\Omega={x\in E:||x||=1}$,$L:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega ,L(x)=-x$

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ is a unit vector in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ and $H = u^\perp$ is the hyperplane orthogonal to $u$, then *reflection in $H$* is the linear transformation $R_u(v) = v - 2\langle u, v\rangle u$.

For example, if $u = \mathbf{e}_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector (so $H$ is the hyperplane $\{x_i = 0\}$), then
$$
R_u(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_{n+1}) = (x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, -x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_{n+1}).
$$