# The degree of the antipodal map without $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher there is a proof that the antipodal map of a sphere $S^n$ has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$ that uses a $\Delta$-complex structure (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528432/the-degree-of-antipodal-map-composition-of-reflections)).

I wonder if there is another proof, that doesn't use the $\Delta$-complex structure. My intuition is that I only need to replace $\Delta_0-\Delta_1$ with the generator of $H_n(U\cap V)$ that appears in the standard Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $S^n$.

Does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your idea the following? If so, then yes this works.

Take the usual cover of the sphere $S^n$ by open neighborhoods of the upper and lower hemispheres, $U$ and $V$. Let $\sigma$ denote the antipodal map. WLOG we can assume that $\sigma U = V$. We also assume that $U\cap V$ deformation retracts onto the equator, $S^{n-1}$.

Then $\sigma$ induces a map of triples $(S^n,U,V)\to (S^n,V,U)$. Thus since $H^n(U)=H^n(V)=H^{n-1}(U)=H^{n-1}(V)=0$ for $n>1$, we get a map of Mayer-Vietoris sequences:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>H_n (S^n) @>\partial_{S^n,U,V}>> H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) @>>> 0 \\
@. @V\sigma_* VV @V\sigma_* VV @. \\
0 @>>>H^n (S^n) @>\partial_{S^n,V,U}>> H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) @>>> 0. \\
\end{CD}
$$

Now the trick is to recall the definition of the boundary map, $\partial_{S^n,U,V}$.
Given a cycle $z \in C_n(S^n)$, find an equivalent cycle of the form $x-y$, with $x$ a cycle in $C_n(U)$, $y$ a cycle of $C_n(V)$, apply the boundary map to the pair $(x,y)$ to get the pair $(\partial x,\partial y)$, then pullback along the inclusion of $C_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\hookrightarrow C_{n-1}(U)\oplus C_{n-1}(V)$. I.e., take the chain $\partial x = \partial y$, which is a chain in $S^{n-1}$.

The only difference when computing the boundary map $\partial_{S^n,V,U}$ is that now we need to have the cycle from $C_n(U)$ be negative. So we write 
$z=(-y)-(-x)$, where $x$ and $y$ are the same cycles as before. Then 
we apply the boundary map to get the pair $(-\partial y, -\partial x)$, then the final chain is $-\partial x = -\partial y$ regarded as an element of $C_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.

Thus $\partial_{S^n,U,V} = -\partial_{S^n,V,U}$.
This says that for $n>1$ 
$$\deg_{S^n}\sigma = -\deg_{S^{n-1}}\sigma.$$
Moreover, since $\deg_{S^1}\sigma=1$, this yields that $\deg_{S^n}\sigma = (-1)^{n+1}$, as desired.

Not sure if this is what you meant, but do let me know.

Comment: This is so clear and beautiful! Thank you very much, this helped me a lot.