# Euler characteristic of an $n$-sphere is $1 + (-1)^n$.

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I am using the textbook Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology* but I am asked to solve a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452107/a-map-without-fixed-points) need this fact that Euler characteristic of sphere is $1 + (-1)^n$.

So may I ask if this is introduced in the text, or this topic is discussed somewhere else?

Thanks~

Comment: WishingFish, are you familiar with cohomology? The Euler characteristic is equal to the alternating sum of the Betti numbers of the cohomology groups (with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients). Equivalently, the Euler characteristic is the alternating sum of the dimensions of the cohomology groups as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients). Do you know the cohomology of the $n$-sphere?

Comment: No, I know some basic thing about DeRham cohomology group from differential topology, but nothing more. Is what you are talking covered in algebraic topology? Thank you, @AmiteshDatta

Comment: The de Rham cohomology of a smooth manifold $M$ is a graded $\mathbb{R}$-vector space: $H^{\text{de Rham}}(M)=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} H^n(M)$; $H^n(M)$ is the $n$th de Rham cohomology group of $M$. The **Poincare series** of this graded $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is the power series $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\dim _{\mathbb{R}} H^n(M))x^n$. The evaluation of the Poincare series at $x=-1$, i.e., $F(-1)$, is defined to be the **Euler characteristic** of $M$. In other words, the Euler characteristic of $M$ is equal to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dim _{\mathbb{R}}(H^n(M))$.

Comment: If $M=\mathbb{S}^n$, then $H^0(M)=\mathbb{R}$, $H^n(M)=\mathbb{R}$, and $H^i(M)=0$ for $i\neq 0,n$. Therefore, the associated Poincare series is $1+x^n$ (it's a polynomial; as is, in fact, always the case for (finite-dimensional) smooth manifolds). If we evaluate this polynomial at $x=-1$, then we obtain the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{S}^n$: i.e., $1+(-1)^n$. So, if you can compute the de Rham cohomology of the sphere, then you can compute the Euler characteristic of the sphere. Can you compute the de Rham cohomology of the sphere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a reference for you, but the computation isn't bad at all.  As a CW-complex, $S^n$ is an $n$-cell whose boundary is glued to a $0$-cell.  The Euler characteristic of an $n$-dimensional CW-complex is the alternating sum $d_0-d_1+d_2-d_3+\ldots+(-1)^nd_n$ where $d_i$ is the number of cells of dimension $i$.  It follows that the Euler characteristic of $S^n$ is $1+(-1)^n$.

Comment: Alternatively, inductively, an $n+1$-sphere is gotten by gluing $2$ $n$-cells to an $n-sphere$, so you can make all the $d_i=2$.

Comment: Hi Jared, I haven't learned $n$-cell and CW-complex. Will it be covered in algebraic topology? For some reason I am doing differential topology first.

Answer (score 7):

A good reference is the Hirsch's book "Differential Topology", page 134. If you don't have the book, I will write here the proof:

" Let $P$ the north pole and $Q=-P$ the south pole. Let $\sigma: S^n - P \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau: S^n - Q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  be the stereographic projections. The coordinate change $\tau \sigma^{-1}= \sigma \tau^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n-0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n-0$ is given by $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|^2}$.

Let $f$ be the vector field on $S^n-P$ whose representation via $\sigma$ is the identity vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow P$ and we define $f(P)=0$. Thus, $f:S^n \rightarrow TS^n$ has zeroes only at $P$ and $Q$.

In $\tau$ coordinates $f$ corresponds to the vector field $x \mapsto -x$ on $S^n-Q$. Thus $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.

The idendity map of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has degree $1$ or $0$, the  antipodal map has degree $(-1)^n$. Therefore $Ind_P f=1$, $Ind_Q f=(-1)^n$.

Thus, we have proved $\chi(S^n)=1+(-1)^n$ "

Answer (score 1):

In Hatcher's algebraic topology, he has a formula $$\chi(M)=\sum_n(-1)^n dim_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_n(M))$$ with $H_n$ being the $n$-th singular homology group. For an $n$-sphere $S^n$, we have $H_0(S^n)=H_n(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ and is $0$ otherwise. So, $$\chi(S^n)=(-1)^0\cdot 1+(-1)^n\cdot 1=1+(-1)^n.$$